# How do I convert a Scala List[org.bson.Document] to a JSON String?

Tags: json, scala, aws-lambda, fasterxml

I had a function in AWS Lambda:

```
def test(pj: Pojo, context: Context): java.util.List[Document]
```

that was not initializing the `pj` with the input JSON values at all.

I found [another way](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/writing-aws-lambda-functions-in-scala/) of doing AWS Lambda in Scala like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

val scalaMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)

def test(input: InputStream, output: OutputStream): Unit = {
  val inputPojo = scalaMapper.readValue(input, classOf[Pojo])
  val answer: Seq[Document] = getTheRealAnswer(inputPojo)
  val jsonStr = "{ frustration: \"I wish my answer was JSON.\" }"
  output.write(jsonStr.getBytes("UTF-8"))
}
```

and that works, except what I really want to return as an answer is a JSON array of Documents.  How should I go about that?

**Edit**:  In my original posting, I wrote:  *"[the first example] was returning the answer as an error 22.  Basically AWS (I think) treated the JSON conversion of the List[Document] as a filename, JSON has plenty of colons, and the error 22 came from colons in filenames not being allowed.  Weird."*  That turned out to be an error in my invocation of the AWS Lambda Function from AWS CLI.  I omitted the output filename in the command invocation, and returned JSON was interpreted by AWS CLI as a filename.

Comment: Can you share your Pojo class? does getTheRealAnswer exist?  You mention ```org.bson.Document``` but not clear to me the mongo calls and what else might be in play. What library are you using to connect to mongo?

Comment: @Barry, since I wrote this message, I got things to work like this:  def jsonizePoints(cDocument: Seq[Document]): String = {val sb=new StringBuilder; for (doc <- cDocument) { if (sb.nonEmpty) {sb.append(",")} sb.append(doc.toJson) } sb.toString}

Comment: Sorry for that big unformatted mess of code in a comment but basically I jsonized each element of the Seq and used StringBuilder to separate the elements with commas.

Comment: As for the Error 22 at the top, that was PEBCAK.  I was invoking aws lambda functions from the command line, I had not specified an output file, and the AWS CLI apparently took my JSON output and said, "Is this your filename?"

Comment: @Barry: This is the Pojo: case class BoundingBox(swLon: Float, swLat: Float, neLon: Float, neLat: Float)

Comment: I was able to initialize the Pojo [BoundingBox] using the second method I outlined above, but not using the first method.

Comment: Yes, getTheRealAnswer exists, but it's called something else, I have it packaged in a JAR.  Basically you call a function with a bounding box, and a search is done in MongoDB, and you get back a Seq[Document].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wrote this message, I got things to work like this:

```
def jsonizeDocs(cDocument: Seq[Document]): String = {
  val sb=new StringBuilder
  for (doc <- cDocument) {
    if (sb.nonEmpty) {
      sb.append(",")
    }
    sb.append(doc.toJson)
  }
  sb.toString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note!** This answer is based on a light wrapper I wrote around [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) which I call [JSON Extensions](https://github.com/onema/jsonextensions)

Assuming you are using Scala Objects, import the `io.onema.json.Extensions._`

```
import io.onema.json.Extensions._

case class Doc(title: String, content: String)

val listOfDocs = Seq(Doc("Foo", "bar"), Doc("Bar", "Baz"), Doc("Blah", "Bax"))
val json: String = listOfDocs.asJson
println(json)  
// [{"title":"Foo","content":"bar"},{"title":"Bar","content":"Baz"},{"title":"Blah","content":"Bax"}]
```

See the [running example here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Y8BWaTGWQziEfKZEQJzY5g)

Now, since you are using a Pojo, you need to import `io.onema.json.JavaExtensions._`. Assuming you have the following POJO:

```
public class Document {
 private String title;
 private String content;
 public String getTitle() {return title;}
 public String getContent() {return content;}
 public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title;}
 public void setContent(String content) {this.content = content;}
}
```

Use this method in your Scala code like such:

```
import io.onema.json.JavaExtensions._
import com.example.Document

// ...

def jsonizeDocs(cDocument: Seq[Document]): String = {
  val json: String = cDocument.asJson
  println(json)
  json
}
```

In AWS Lambda (and to go the other way around) use `jsonDecode` and a custom object mapper to deserialize to the expected type:

```
import io.onema.json.JavaExtensions._
import io.onema.json.Mapper
import com.example.Document

val jsonString = """[{"title":"Foo","content":"bar"},{"title":"Bar","content":"Baz"},{"title":"Blah","content":"Bax"}]"""
val mapper: ObjectMapper = Mapper.allowUnknownPropertiesMapper
val doc: Document = jsonString.jsonDecode[Document](mapper)
```

I have used the method described here quite successfully in a lambda framework that is able to deserialize to AWS lambda events as well as custom types, see a [simple example here](https://github.com/onema/uServerless/blob/master/userverless-tests/src/test/scala/functions/simple/EchoFunction.scala).

That's it! you can use this library or one of the many JSON serializers in Java or Scala. If you know the type of your objects most libraries will enable you to serialize to JSON and back very easily.